# Intuition for Nagata's altitude formula?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry

This is theorem 14.C on p.84 of Matsumura's commutative algebra.

> Let $A$ be a noetherian domain, and let $B$ be a finitely generated overdomain of $A$. Let $P \in Spec(B)$ and $p = P \cap A$. Then we have 
>   $ht(P) \leq ht(p) + tr.d._{A} B - tr.d._{K(p)} K(P)$ with equality holds when $A$ is universally catenary or if $B$ is a polynomial ring over $A$.

Question: How should one understand this formula? I'm hazarding a guess that this factor, $tr.d._{A} B - tr.d._{K(p)}K(P)$, can somehow measure how primes of $B$ will be identified when they are restricted back to $A$. But this sounds woefully wrong and I just want to know how I should view this result or whether there is any (geometric) intuition behind the result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put dim B=n for the dimension of the variety with coordinates ring B. Then


n-ht P ≥ ((n-tr deg <sub>A</sub> B)- ht p)+ tr deg <sub>*k*(p)</sub> *k*(P)


The first member of the inequality indicates the dimension of the subvariety definited by P.

The term (n-tr deg <sub>A</sub> B) in the second member is the dimension of the variety with coordinates ring A: it looses 
tr deg <sub>A</sub> B dimensions with respect the other variety with coordinate ring B.

Then ((n-tr deg <sub>A</sub> B)- ht p) represent the dimension of the subvariety definited by p.

The term tr deg <sub>*k*(p)</sub> *k*(P) is a corrector term because blow up can occur.

Comment: hmm, this looks reasonable for finitely generated k-algebras. Just to be safe, what you have said is not going to be true for an arbitrary noetherian domain right?